# How acces to the values of a Set

Tags: dart, flutter, angular-dart

I'am a begginer in Dart and  i dont know how to acces to the values of the next Set

```
Set mySet = Set.from(['Please', 'Help', 'Me']);
```

Comment: What do you mean by accessing value of next set ??

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*I didn't get the clarity of what you mean by accessing next set but, you can access your current set data in following ways.*

```
Set mySet = Set.from(['Please', 'Help', 'Me']); // declaration.
```

Accessing through index

```
print('mySet.elementAt(0): ${mySet.elementAt(0)}');
print('mySet.elementAt(1): ${mySet.elementAt(1)}');
print('mySet.elementAt(2): ${mySet.elementAt(2)}');
```

Iterating over set.

```
mySet.forEach((value) => {print(value)});
```

Logging to see data stored in current set.

```
print('mySet: ${mySet.toString()}');
```

Comment: You have solved my doubt in an excellent way. Thank you! This is just what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

From Wikipedia:

> > Unlike most other collection types, rather than retrieving a specific element from a set, one typically tests a value for membership in a set.

That is, if this is not possible (to acces to the values) then this does not mean that this data structure does not fulfill its purpose.
Maybe you should choose a different, and at the same time, more suitable, for your purposes, data structure?

Comment: Thank you for this information, it had been difficult to understand what paper was already playing in difference between with List